# Calculate font size based on characters in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create method which will read the all characters in text box and return font size value.

my function is not working correct.  Below is my code

```
    function sizeInput(input) {
    return shrinkToFill(input, 48, '', 'Impact');
}
function shrinkToFill(input, fontSize, fontWeight, fontFamily) {
    var font = fontWeight + ' ' + fontSize + 'px ' + fontFamily;
    var $input = $(input);
    var maxWidth = $input.width() - 50;

    // we're only concerned with the largest line of text.
    var longestLine = $input.val().split('\n').sort(function (a, b) {
        return measureText(a, font).width - measureText(b, font).width;
    }).pop();

    var textWidth = measureText(longestLine, font).width;
    if (textWidth >= maxWidth) {
        // if it's too big, calculate a new font size
        // the extra .9 here makes up for some over-measures
        fontSize = fontSize * maxWidth / textWidth * 0.9;
        font = fontWeight + ' ' + fontSize + 'px ' + fontFamily;
        // and set the style on the input

    }
    else {
        font = fontWeight + ' ' + fontSize + 'px ' + fontFamily;
        // and set the style on the input        
    }
    $input.css({
        'font-size': fontSize
    });
    return fontSize;
}
var measureText = function (str, font) {
    str = str.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');
    var id = 'text-width-tester';
    var $tag = $('#' + id);
    if (!$tag.length) {
        $tag = $('<span id="' + id + '" style="display:none;font:' + font + ';">' + str + '</span>');
        $('body').append($tag);
    } else {
        $tag.css({
            font: font
        }).html(str);
    }
    return {
        width: $tag.width(),
        height: $tag.height()
    };
};
var topText = $('#topText');
var bottomText = $('#bottomText');

var textUpdated = function () {
    var topFontSize = sizeInput(topText);
    var bottomFontSize = sizeInput(bottomText);
};
```

It doesn't return any error but it doesn't work.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to read the applicable css?

Comment: Check my updated code, I want only simple method which return font size based on chanrecter.

Comment: Could you put it in jsFiddle and then add the link,?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Nayeem_Mansoori/5bdLomyp/

Comment: You didn't add any css to the fiddle.

Comment: @Difster thanks for quick reply but did not use it's jquery function i need to make new method for calculate character and return font size ..

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/5bdLomyp/2/

```js
var sizeInput = function(input) {
    return shrinkToFill(input, 48, '', 'Impact');
}

var shrinkToFill = function(input, fontSize, fontWeight, fontFamily) {
    var font = fontWeight + ' ' + fontSize + 'px ' + fontFamily;
    var $input = $(input);
    var maxWidth = $input.width() - 50;

    // we're only concerned with the largest line of text.
    var longestLine = $input.val().split('\n').sort(function (a, b) {
        return measureText(a, font).width - measureText(b, font).width;
    }).pop();

    var textWidth = measureText(longestLine, font).width;
    if (textWidth >= maxWidth) {
        // if it's too big, calculate a new font size
        // the extra .9 here makes up for some over-measures
        fontSize = fontSize * maxWidth / textWidth * 0.9;
        font = fontWeight + ' ' + fontSize + 'px ' + fontFamily;
        // and set the style on the input
       
    }
    else {
        font = fontWeight + ' ' + fontSize + 'px ' + fontFamily;
        // and set the style on the input        
    }
    $input.css({
        'font-size': fontSize
    });
    return fontSize;
}
var measureText = function (str, font) {
    str = str.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');
    var id = 'text-width-tester';
    var $tag = $('#' + id);
    if (!$tag.length) {
        $tag = $('<span id="' + id + '" style="display:none;font:' + font + ';">' + str + '</span>');
        $('body').append($tag);
    } else {
        $tag.css({
            font: font
        }).html(str);
    }
    return {
        width: $tag.width(),
        height: $tag.height()
    };
};

var topText = $('#topText');
var bottomText = $('#bottomText');

$('#topText, #bottomText').keyup(function(){
  var topFontSize = sizeInput(topText);
   var bottomFontSize = sizeInput(bottomText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="topText" class="hide text-tool top-text" type="text" placeholder="Top Text" />
<input id="bottomText" class="hide text-tool bottom-text" type="text" placeholder="Bottom Text" />
```

I guess this is what you are looking for.

Instead of using **onkeyup** or **onchange** in HTML, I have used **jQuery** **keyup** feature.

Comment: But when i back character  then it will not work perfectly

Comment: Thankyou @Shiladitya

Comment: Welcome @NayeemMansoori :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer :

```
function getFontSize(targetInput) {
        var input = $("<input>").css({ "width": "570px", "height": "52px", "text-align": "center", "font-size": "48px" })
        .val($(targetInput).val());
        var topFontSize = sizeInput(input);
        return topFontSize;
    }
```